# how to post a file or stdout into a http server?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I would like to execute some command then send them into my web server for analysis.

somethink like :

```
wmic csproduct get | wget http://someserver/cgi-bin/hello.pl
```

Except that wget is not delivered out-of-the-box by Microsoft.

How can I make the same using stuff that are delivered with Windows 2000 and futher?  Can vbscript do the job?

Comment: Yes, you can send data to a webserver with VBScript. However, the details depend heavily on what kind of API that web interface implements.

Comment: The idea is to make an analisys for making my own analyser.

Comment: That doesn't change anything about what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: Cannot understand why it is unclear...

Comment: Then you may want to do some research on web APIs. Is yours a REST API? SOAP? A custom CGI/ASP/whatever API? A web form? Does it require GET requests? POST? PUT? PATCH?

Comment: The question is not about the un-serialization of the data.  I consider the REST API, SOAP, PUT, GET just as constant values or if you prefer implementation details...  I really do not care!

Comment: Are you kidding me? We cannot tell you how you can send data to your web server unless we know how that webserver expects the data to be sent in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you executing some commands to get your information, may be it would be more native to use a command shell environment?
How about PowerShell?

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).UploadString("http://someserver/cgi-bin/hello.pl", (Get-WMIObject Win32_BIOS) )
```

[read about the UploadString() method here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_UploadString_System_Uri_System_String_)

If you still want to stick to a vbscript solution, here is a sample code which accepts a text from stdin and posts it to your server:

```
Dim inp, http_req
inp = inp & WScript.StdIn.ReadAll()
WScript.Echo "Input: " & inp

Set http_req = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
http_req.open "POST", "http://someserver/cgi-bin/hello.pl", false
http_req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
http_req.send inp
```

[The minimum requirements seems to be Windows 2000 Professional with SP3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttprequest) , i personnaly tested the script with Windows XP.